# Doing multiple regression without intercept in R (without changing data dimensions)

Tags: r, regression, multiple-regression, intercept

I am trying to calculate multiple regression in `R` without intercept.

My data is as follow:

```
    y  <- c(60.323,61.122,60.171,61.187,63.221,63.639,64.989,63.761,66.019,67.857,68.169,66.513,68.655,69.564,69.331,70.551)
    x1 <- c(83,88.5,88.2,89.5,96.2,98.1,99,100,101.2,104.6,108.4,110.8,112.6,114.2,115.7,116.9)
    x2 <- c(107.608,108.632,109.773,110.929,112.075,113.27,115.094,116.219,117.388,118.734,120.445,121.95,123.366,125.368,127.852,130.081)
```

In this case, (I believe?) I am getting the coefficients WITH intercept:

```
lm(formula = y ~ x1 + x2)
```

I would like to get the coefficients WITHOUT intercept. I tried this:

```
lm(formula = y ~ x1 + x2 -1)
```

Is this correct? If so, my question would be: How can I calculate WITHOUT intercept without changing the x values (on the right side of the tilde), but by changing something on the y value (on the left side of the tilde). For instance:

```
lm(formula = y -1 ~ x1 + x2)
```

Gets a different (and presumably incorrect coefficient estimation).

I know your question is ... why do you have to only change the y values? The reason is because I am writing code in C to do this, and I do not want to change the dimensions of X by adding a -1 at the end because that would require dynamic array allocation, which is very meticulous for me.

Comment: You can't. Including `- 1` on the LHS just subtracts 1 from the DV. Coefficients are only estimated for the RHS. I'm not sure I follow your rationale.

Comment: I am not sure I follow you rationale either. Anyway... this may be of help: model.matrix() returns the design matrix of your model object.

Comment: This is documented in `?lm`. In order to remove intercept you can do either `y ~ x - 1` or `y ~ 0 + x` so `lm(formula = y ~ x1 + x2 -1)` or similarly `lm(formula = y ~ 0 + x1 + x2)` is the way to go.

Comment: @DavidArenburg Please read my comment again and more carefully. I'm not wrong.

Comment: @Roland, right, you meant to the second option mentioned by the OP.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The formula

```
lm(formula = y ~ x1 + x2)
```

will include an intercept by default.

The formula

```
lm(formula = y ~ x1 + x2 -1)
```

or

```
lm(formula = y ~ x1 + x2 +0)
```

is how R estimates an OLS model without an intercept. The formula

```
lm(formula = y-1 ~ x1 + x2)
```

estimates a model against a dependent variable `y` with 1 subtracted from it.

Centering all terms at their mean will also enforce a zero intercept.